# Gap between objects created using array modifier objects

Tags: modifiers

I was following an online course to learn blender on Udemy. I was using array modifier to create an array of objects using array modifier. The relative offset is set to (0,0,1), and I was expecting objects to be right next to each other without any gaps. Whereas I get something like this:
[image]

I could get rid of the gap by decreasing relative offset value along z. But I wanted to understand what's giving me this gap, while the online course used the same relative offset and had no gaps.

Details of a single object: it is made up of 4 cylinders with a non-default property "Nothing".

[Edited] Screenshot from the video that I am following:
[image]
You can see no gap between two objects. I see that we used same settings.

Comment: are you sure there's not a single vertex hanging on the bottom?

Comment: No, I do not think so. These are just 4 cylinder objects. I tried making them from scratch, and still the same result.

Comment: is ther a stray vertex somwere?

Comment: Left side appears "taller" than right

Answer (score 1):

Tick the Merge checkbox in the array modifier. It is most likely that your instructor too had used Merge option ticked

Comment: No, that's not the case. I just checked, and also attached a screenshot from the video.

Answer (score 0):

**Not symmetrical**

If you look closely the left side of your scaffold is a wee bit higher than the right.  This makes the z dimension a bit bigger both ways, hence the gap.

[image: **enter image description here**]

Example with two joined cubes, one slightly higher than the other. Make same and array will merge as expected.